# Pygame - Unknown error in a multiplayer control function

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am making a two player game in which two players can move simultaneously throughout.

The while loop goes like this:

```
while stop==0:

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        stop = 1

        #For player 1
    #on pressing an arrow key
    # xv, yv = velocity at which the object moves
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            xv = -1
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            xv = 1
        elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            yv = -1
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            yv = 1
            #         on releasing an arrow key
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:

        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            xv = 0
        elif event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            yv = 0

    #For player 2

    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            xv2 = -1
        elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
            xv2 = 1
        elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
            yv2 = -1
        elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
            yv2 = 1
                #         on releasing an arrow key
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:

        if event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_d:
            xv2 = 0
        elif event.key == pygame.K_w or event.key == pygame.K_s:
            yv2 = 0
```

Using the above code, only player 1 was able to move while player 2 remained still.

but after modifying the code like this it worked,

```
while stop==0:

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        stop = 1

        #For player 1
     #on pressing an arrow key
    # xv, yv = velocity at which the object moves
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            xv = -1
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            xv = 1
        elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            yv = -1
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            yv = 1
            #         on releasing an arrow key
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:

        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            xv = 0
        elif event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            yv = 0

    #For player 2
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        stop = 1
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            xv2 = -1
        elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
            xv2 = 1
        elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
            yv2 = -1
        elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
            yv2 = 1
                #         on releasing an arrow key
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:

        if event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_d:
            xv2 = 0
        elif event.key == pygame.K_w or event.key == pygame.K_s:
            yv2 = 0
```

The only change made was inserting

```
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        stop = 1
```

before the elif statement of player 2. Can anyone help with this confusion?

Comment: It is just that in your first version you have two `elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:` cases in the same `if...elif...elif...` chain. So the second one never occurred. In the second version you split the `elif` chain into two by inserting the additional `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    # player1
elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: # <-- this will never checked
    # player2
```

Second `pygame.KEYDOWN` will be never use because first `pygame.KEYDOWN` catchs all `KEYDOWN` events.

You need only one `pygame.KEYDOWN`

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    # player1
    # player2
elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
    # player1
    # player2
```

or you have to use two `if`

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    # player1
elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
    # player1


if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    # player2
elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
    # player2
```

---

BTW. when you will use Classes then you will have two objects with own method to check events

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
   # quit

player1.handle_event(event)
player2.handle_event(event)
```

and every player will have own

```
def handle_event(self, event)
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        # do something
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        # do something
```